# Version History of Database entries in entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, database-design

I have a project where I want to keep version history of each changes. For instance, in following example if somebody changes information like:

1. Add a new task to person
2. Edit a existing task
3. Add a  new person in a group or edit an existing persons information
4. Add a new group or edit an existing group

Here is a picture of my structure:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7YwG.png]

It will create a new version of project. It seems that it will duplicate many existing data. Could anyone suggest a solution for this problem.

Real project has lots of one to many relationship and expected solution for end user desires central version of each modification.

I am using ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework for this problem.

Comment: what do you mean by keep a history, take a copy or all the data?  why not just turn everything to json and store it as a blob

Comment: Hello Thewads thanks for your reply. But I want to do this in database.

Comment: Hi again Thewads, can I have any example of such practice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no answer, I solved the problem by adding one additional table for each table. following slowly changing dimension type 4: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension 
However it will be nice to get some other ideas regarding this issue.

Here is a picture of my solution: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhvQi.png
[image: Version History of Database entries in entity framework]

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using EF, I presumably can say that there are model classes which are XML serializable. So why don't you just serialize a snapshot of a model and save it in a table with a date time stamp attached to it and keep the latest version always in the table? Whenever you need the old version you just take it and deserialize and then render.

This way you always work on the latest version, which is actually supposed to be happened and keep old versions in a xml dump in case you need them.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, Can I have any example of such practice ?

Comment: if you mean running site? then i know this one - http://www.qualityforum.org/Home.aspx. how? I was once an employee in the development section